# Transforming svg to pdf not exact image in pdf: text issue

Tags: java, svg, batik

Hi all here is my codes in svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="800" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1200 800" width="1200">
<g stroke-width="200"
  transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 800)">
    <g transform="translate(400,400) scale(0.0029) rotate(-0.0)">

        <text fill="black"
                 font-family="monospace"
                 font-size="23120.0"
                 text-anchor="middle"
                 transform="scale(1,-1)"
                 x="-23920.0"
                 y="115625.0">D</text>
        <rect fill="none"
                 height="28900.0"
                 stroke="blue"
                 stroke-width="100"
                 width="23920.0"
                 x="-35880.0"
                 y="-122850.0"/>                        

    </g>
</g>
```

sample output in svg:

[image]

but when i try to transcode it with batik and tranform it to pdf format it looks like this:

[image: pdf img]

Comment: For the text: The svg doesn't save font information. I mean, it saves the name, but "monospace" is a variety of fonts, depending on the OS and program you run. You need to rasterize your svg in order to keep the text as you written it.

Comment: @BackSlash rasterize means converting to bitmap, I think you mean converting the text to curves.

Comment: @Duopixel Yes, I meant this. In inkscape, when saving to PDF, it's called rasterizing. It doesn't produce a bitmap, it just converts text to curves, that's why I said "rasterize".

Comment: @BlackSlash ah, then Inkscape has the term wrong https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasterisation (not being pedantic, just so the OP knows he's not supposed to convert to bitmap!)

Comment: Hi guys can you give me an example on how to do it? rasterize my svg.